# All borders color not changing (only bottom and right borders changing)

Tags: html, css, jqwidget

On validation of a JqxGrid, i would like to change the borders of cell to RED color if the cell has empty values.
I managed to highlight the borders of cells, but only bottom and right borders are in RED, what i am missing in highlighting all borders?

Click the button ‘click to validate’ to see the error-ed cell borders in RED

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ranadheemachineni/2pzLorvc/6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // prepare the data
  var data = new Array();

  var row1 = {};
  row1["firstname"] = 'Andrew';
  row1["secondname"] = 'A';

  var row2 = {};
  row2["firstname"] = '';
  row2["secondname"] = '';

  var row3 = {};
  row3["firstname"] = '';
  row3["secondname"] = 'C';

  data.push(row1);
  data.push(row2);
  data.push(row3);

  var source = {
    localdata: data,
    datatype: "array"
  };

  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
    width: "100%",
    source: source,
    autoheight: true,
    editable: true,
    editmode: 'selectedcell',
    selectionmode: 'singlecell',
    columns: [{
        text: 'First Name',
        datafield: 'firstname',
        width: 150,
        cellsalign: 'left'
      },

      {
        text: 'Second Name',
        datafield: 'secondname',
        width: 150,
        cellsalign: 'left'
      }
    ]
  });

  $("#btn").on('click', function() {
    var columns = ['firstname', 'secondname'];
    $.each(columns, function(colIndex, eachColumn) {
      $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('setcolumnproperty', eachColumn,
        'cellclassname',
        function(row, columnfield, value) {
          if (value == undefined || value.length == 0) {
            return 'erroredcolumn';
          }
        });
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.erroredcolumn {
  border-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/generatedata.js"></script>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
  <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click to validate" />
```

Comment: add   .erroredcolumn {
             border-color: red !important;
             top:1px;
             border-width:1px 1px 1px 1px !important;
        }

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // prepare the data
            var data = new Array();
       
            var row1 = {};
            row1["firstname"] = 'Andrew';
            row1["secondname"] = 'A';
       
            var row2 = {};
            row2["firstname"] = '';
            row2["secondname"] = '';

      var row3 = {};
            row3["firstname"] = '';
            row3["secondname"] = 'C';
            
            data.push(row1);
            data.push(row2);
            data.push(row3);

      var source = {
                localdata: data,
                datatype: "array"
            };
            
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
                width: "100%",
                source: source,
                autoheight: true,
                editable: true,
              editmode: 'selectedcell',
          selectionmode: 'singlecell',
                columns: [{
                    text: 'First Name',
                    datafield: 'firstname',
                    width: 150,
                    cellsalign: 'left'
                },

                {
                    text: 'Second Name',
                    datafield: 'secondname',
                    width: 150,
                    cellsalign: 'left'
                }]
            });
            
           $("#btn").on('click', function () {
            var columns = ['firstname', 'secondname'];
            $.each( columns, function( colIndex, eachColumn ) {
           $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('setcolumnproperty', eachColumn,
                 'cellclassname', function (row, columnfield, value) {
                     if (value == undefined || value.length == 0) {
              return 'erroredcolumn';
           }
                  });
            });
            });

        });
```

```css
       .erroredcolumn {
             border-color: red !important;
             top:1px;
             border-width:1px 1px 1px 1px !important;
        }
        .jqx-grid-cell{
            
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/generatedata.js"></script>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
    <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click to validate" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `position` so when you apply `border-color` so it hide the `top-border` because you doesn't assigned `position` `top` so `border-top` hidden by grey `border`.

Just add following css

**[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2pzLorvc/7/)**

```
   .erroredcolumn {
         border: 1px solid red !important;
         top:1px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response. its working fine, there is a minor misalignment. Is there any way to fix?